# OneToMany with different "owners" Doctrine (but not only)

Tags: relational, orm

I have an Attachment Entity where I store files that users could attach inside various content types entities.

Now I'm in troubles with the relationships between every "content type" entity and the Attachment Entity.

I was trying a OneToMany association with JoinTable, but it create a JoinTable for every relation type. For ex. if I have a blog and a mail entities that could host attachments Doctrine will create two tables: blogs_attachments and mail_attachments.

But what if I need to know the "owner" of a concrete Attachment record?

Could anyone please help me?

thank you!

Comment: http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm.html